# The string argument 'migrationId' cannot be empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

Apologies in advance if this has already been answered but I've honestly dug deep and could not find anything relating to this error.

In a nutshell, I am unable to make any updates to my database using code first within my ASP.NET Core 1.1.2 project. It's throwing an exception because it's missing an argument which I'm guessing is not to do with PMC.

Error message when using 'Update-Database':

[image: Error-Image-Update-Database]

Text for cross checking Google ;-)

```
    System.ArgumentException: The string argument 'migrationId' cannot be empty.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Check.NotEmpty(String value, String parameterName)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.GetAppliedMigrations()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
The string argument 'migrationId' cannot be empty.
```

The Migrations folder is identical to my '_EFMigrationsHistory' table (ignoring the last migration which is scheduled for update):

[image]

I've even gone as far as removing the Migrations folder and '_EFMigrationsHistory' table and starting again which presented the same error. I was also going to test 'v2.0.0-preview2-final' just in case it was a bug, but sadly my version of VS only takes release builds and apparently you need 15.3.

Version Info:

- Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 - 15.2 (26430.16) Release
- Entity Framework Core v1.1.2
- ASP.NET Core v1.1.2

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

**Edit**

@DavidG

For  `dotnet ef database update`

[image]

and for `Update-Database -TargetMigration AdUserImage`

[image]

Comment: What happens if you specify a target migration? For example: `Update-Database -TargetMigration AdUserImage`

Comment: Or use the EF Core CLI: `dotnet ef database update`

Comment: Try this, first delete **migration folder** then delete **migration history** from database and then try to run `add-migration` and `update-database`.

Comment: Yeah, that was my thought too (target the migration explicitly). You shouldn't *have* to do that, but based on the error, it sounds like that might fix it. Kind of a pain to have to do every time, but at least it might give you a workaround.

Comment: How did you create the last migration? It looks a bit strange in your Migrations folder, wasn't there some problem during creation?

Comment: @DavidG See Edit.

Comment: @UtkarshDubey This was one of the first things I did and still no joy.

Comment: @M.Pipal I had an issue previously where Migrations table was out of sync, so I started again using the methods Utkarsh mentioned.

Comment: @Kitson88 Try to execute this - `Update-Database -TargetMigration:"name_of_migration"
`.

Comment: Are you running those commands from the project folder where the context is located and not the solution level?

Comment: or you can Check this out - https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Jan/13/Resetting-Entity-Framework-Migrations-to-a-clean-Slate

Comment: @DavidG I'm guessing it's solution level but not sure how to confirm.

Comment: @UtkarshDubey 'TargetMigration' is not a parameter on my version of 'Update-Database'.

Comment: Use `pwd` command to print the directory you are in.

Comment: @DavidG it's at the root folder of the solution.

Comment: `dotnet` command needs to be run in the project folder.

Comment: @DavidG Thanks. Just browsing and testing now

Comment: @DavidG Apologies but just to confirm, do you want me to run dotnet command of the .DLL in the bin folder using the ef switch?

Comment: No, in the folder where the csproj file is for the project containing the EF code.

Comment: @DavidG The same error that's pictured above running inside the root of the project folder.

Comment: As in `no executable found`?

Comment: @DavidG Yes that's correct.

Comment: Seems you are missing the EF Core CLI, can you install them like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet#install-by-editing-project)?

Comment: @DavidG Thanks for you help David and yes I'll give it a try. Failing that It will be a re-install of Win10 & VS.

Comment: @DavidG The issue was down to me installing Dotnet 2.0.0 sometime ago when it was first released (Not sure why I've only started having the issue now but hey ho). VS was using this as it's primary Dotnet which now make's sense about this weird issues with EF. Thank you so much for putting me on the right tracks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally resolved the issue thanks to @DavidG putting me on the right direction so thank you very much.

I realised that when I was checking the installed SDK's on my PC, I noticed that I've installed a pre-release of Dotnet 2.0.0 (I honestly can't remember doing this). Checking the Dotnet version (`dotnet --version`) from PMC confirmed VS was using 2.0.0. After uninstalling all Dotnet SDK's and runtimes and then re-installing the latest release of Dotnet(1.1.2) from [here](https://github.com/dotnet/core/releases/tag/v1.1.2), `Update-Database` was working as should...few!