# 'The string argument 'migrationId' cannot be empty.'

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-migrations, asp.net-core-1.1

Blocked on a weird error. I am working in an asp.net core web application, and using EF core 1.1.0 in it.

EF database migration is throwing error 'The string argument 'migrationId' cannot be empty.' when trying to execute below command

```
dbcontext.Database.Migrate();
```

**Performed accepted answer from the the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45282303/the-string-argument-migrationid-cannot-be-empty) but it did not solved my issue.**

```
Uninstall donet 2.0.0, installed 1.1.0 and restarted PC. Still i am getting the same error.
```

Can anyone please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had solved my issue.

Just deleted development database and executed migration on start.

It working now perfectly.

Answer (score 10):

When you have MigrationID column with in __EFMigrationsHistory table is empty you will have above issue. Make sure you delete this record manually and rerun the command. Please find screen shot for the same.

[image]