# ASP.NET Core error occurred during publish and site is not working

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core

In ASP.NET Core I added a new column to my database and now when I publish  I get an error
[image]

I am trying to add `CourierId` to my `Prescriptions` table, it works in debug but fails to publish and my website is currently down as well. In the error it says `"IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT*FROM[_EFMigrationHisto"` and `FK_Prescriptions_Courier_Courierid is not a valid contstraint.` I am using SQL Here is the code for my `Couriers` table and `Prescriptions` table

```
public class Courier
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Prescription> Prescriptions { get; set; }
}
public class Prescription
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //[NotMapped]
    //public string Courier { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Courier")]
    public int? CourierId { get; set; }
    public virtual Courier Courier { get; set; }
}
```

How can I add the `CourierId` column to `Prescriptions`? Publish and have the website work?

Comment: did you do migration?

Comment: @Alexan yes I did a migration and update-database and it said `string argument 'migrationId' cannot be empty` and I would get a 'sqlexception invalid columnId' after trying it multiple times I went into sql server and added the table and column manually and everything worked but now when I publish this happens

Comment: So basically update-database says `string argument 'migartionId' cannot be empty`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46340201/240564

Comment: @Alexan thank you, however if I do delete the development database, what exactly does that do, is it how it sounds? Will all of my test data be deleted? Or is it similar to like a 'drop and recreate data'? And I'm assuming it won't affect the actual data on my database too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer thanks to the comments @Alexan, I have a new problem now but I will have to work on that outside of this post. My migration had a lot of extra code and after commenting it out, I published and it ran fine. Originally nothing was commented

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
            name: "CourierId",
            table: "Prescriptions",
            nullable: true);
        //migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
        //    name: "FK_Prescriptions_Couriers_CourierId",
        //    table: "Prescriptions");

        //migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<int>(
        //    name: "CourierId",
        //    table: "Prescriptions",
        //    nullable: true,
        //    oldClrType: typeof(int));

        //migrationBuilder.InsertData(
        //    table: "Couriers",
        //    columns: new[] { "Id", "Name" },
        //    values: new object[] { 1, "Akeem" });

        //migrationBuilder.InsertData(
        //    table: "Couriers",
        //    columns: new[] { "Id", "Name" },
        //    values: new object[] { 2, "Mitch" });

        //migrationBuilder.InsertData(
        //    table: "Couriers",
        //    columns: new[] { "Id", "Name" },
        //    values: new object[] { 3, "Devin" });

        //migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
        //    name: "FK_Prescriptions_Couriers_CourierId",
        //    table: "Prescriptions",
        //    column: "CourierId",
        //    principalTable: "Couriers",
        //    principalColumn: "Id",
        //    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
            name: "CourierId",
            table: "Prescriptions");
        //migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
        //    name: "FK_Prescriptions_Couriers_CourierId",
        //    table: "Prescriptions");

        //migrationBuilder.DeleteData(
        //    table: "Couriers",
        //    keyColumn: "Id",
        //    keyValue: 1);

        //migrationBuilder.DeleteData(
        //    table: "Couriers",
        //    keyColumn: "Id",
        //    keyValue: 2);

        //migrationBuilder.DeleteData(
        //    table: "Couriers",
        //    keyColumn: "Id",
        //    keyValue: 3);

        //migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<int>(
        //    name: "CourierId",
        //    table: "Prescriptions",
        //    nullable: false,
        //    oldClrType: typeof(int),
        //    oldNullable: true);

        //migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
        //    name: "FK_Prescriptions_Couriers_CourierId",
        //    table: "Prescriptions",
        //    column: "CourierId",
        //    principalTable: "Couriers",
        //    principalColumn: "Id",
        //    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
    }
}
```

So now the problem is `Courier` table is not created but `CourierId` is added to `Prescriptions` table and it publishes, so now I think I will need to uncomment the `migrationBuilder.InsertData` but I will see.